# Avoid untrusted/unescaped variables in DML query error

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql

I'm building dynamic queries in few of my apex methods. When I run the PMD code review, i'm running into the "Avoid untrusted/unescaped variables in DML query" error. Running into 3 dynamic query errors(queries below). I did escape for the 2'nd query but still erroring out.

1. ```
   sQuery += ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Id IN :recentIds';
       In the where clause, I've a list<Id> and how do I escape the list<Id>?
   ```
2. ```
   searchText = '%' + searchText + '%';//escaping the searchText variable for 
    where clause
    sQuery += ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE ';

            if (queryFields == null || queryFields.isEmpty()) {
                sQuery += ' Name LIKE :searchText ';
            }
   ```

   I'm escaping the "searchText" before querying but still running into error. Can I know what is wrong?
3. sQuery += ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Id = :id';

In the above query, i'm filtering by comparing record id to "Id" variable. how do I escape the variable here?

update:

```
List<Id> recentIds = new List<Id>();
        for(RecentlyViewed recent : [SELECT Id FROM RecentlyViewed WHERE Type = :objectName ORDER BY LastViewedDate DESC LIMIT :maxResults]) {
            recentIds.add(recent.Id);
        }
        
        String sQUERY = 'SELECT Id, ';
        
        if (returnFields != null && returnFields.Size() > 0) {
            sQuery += String.join(returnFields, ',');
        } else {
            sQuery += 'Name';   
        }
        
        sQuery += ' FROM ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName) + ' WHERE Id IN :recentIds';
        
        List<sObject> searchResult = Database.query(sQuery);
```

Comment: Are you sure you're actually escaping anything here? `'%' + thing + '%'` is _not_ escaping. Escaping is when you have a string like `'look at me, I've got a single quote in me'` and change it to explicitly use "escape" sequences for potentially problematic characters (e.g. `'I've'` => `'I\'ve'`). There's more to it than that, but comments can only be so long.

Comment: Does it actually say "DML Query"? Because that terminology is wrong at a very basic level.

Comment: For 1 and 3 your `objectName` is what is unescaped.

Comment: yes, the error says "Avoid untrusted/unescaped variables in DML query"

Comment: That is really disappointing and kind of hard to believe.

Comment: It should be just "Query" or "SOQL Query". I guess the rule description is wrong. Is this the tool? If yes, you can submit a documentation issue. The description and explanation are entirely different. https://docs.qualityclouds.com/qcd/avoid-using-untrusted-unescaped-variables-in-dml-queries-31720310.html

Answer (score 2):

You seem to misunderstand what escaping is. Wrapping in wildcard characters has nothing to do with this vulnerability. Instead, you need to pass any directly merged variables to `String.escapeSingleQuotes`.

**Unescaped**

```
sQuery += ' FROM ' + objectName + ' WHERE Id IN :recentIds';
```

**Escaped**

```
sQuery += ' FROM ' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(objectName) + ' WHERE Id IN :recentIds';
```